# Amazon DynamoDB : Fine-Grained Access Control with Scan seems not possible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-simpledb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have a very simple table with 3 fields :

1. uuid (String)
2. firstname (String)
3. accepted (Boolean)

I would like to know if a user policy would allow two actions "Scan" and "PutItem" with two conditions:

1. For Scan: Scan all accepted=true (only permits that condition but I don't know if it's possible). It would be a like a "view".
2. For PutItem: Protect the accepted field.

### What I tried

I just tried a basic approach :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "LimitAccessToSpecificAttributes",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:Scan",
                "dynamodb:PutItem"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:xxx:table/mytable"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "dynamodb:Attributes": [
                        "uuid",
                        "firstname",
                        "accepted"
                    ]
                },
                "StringEqualsIfExists": {
                    "dynamodb:Select": "SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES",
                    "dynamodb:ReturnValues": [
                        "NONE",
                        "UPDATED_OLD",
                        "UPDATED_NEW"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If I remove "accepted", I can't use ScanFilter based on it.

Do I have to set two users with two separate policies ?

The hardest part seems to hide all items with `accepted:false`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is this "Stmt1467962302000" change that to "LimitAccessToSpecificAttributes"